# stream adapters in Stream Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, io

Below is a picture from C# 7.0 in a Nutshell book:
[image]

Q1-from the picture, it can be inferred that only backing store streams e.g. FileStream can "connect" to files directly, but isn't that we can use StreamReader/StreamWriter to read/write to the file directly?

Q2-The book also says:

**An adapter wraps a stream, just like a decorator. Unlike a decorator, however, an adapter is not itself a stream; it typically hides the byte-oriented methods completely**

But isn't that StreamReader/StreamWriter etc labelled as Stream Adapters in the picture? how could they be called "Stream Adapter" if they are not considered as streams?

Comment: Q1) In order for the `StreamWriter` / `StreamReader` to write/read from a file they need to be constructed using a `FileStream`.  A `FileStream` itself can write/read directly from the file. 
Q2) They are adapters because you can't use them as a stream anymore i.e. you can't decorate the `StreamReader` in a `GZipStream`. However you can decorate a `GZipStream` using another decorator because the decorator itself is a `Stream` object.

Comment: Re-examine the word "directly". A `new StreamReader("file.txt")` creates a FileStream under the hood. The picture is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> how could they be called "Stream Adapter" if they are not considered as streams

The same way a cup holder can't be considered a cup.

> isn't that we can use StreamReader/StreamWriter to read/write to the file directly?

StreamWriter/Reader uses Stream internally.
From the source code: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs#L192

Answer (score 1):

### Q1

Only the backing store streams connects directly to the specific I/O resource. You use a `MemoryStream` to read/write a data stream to the memory. The `StreamWriter` *uses* a e.g. `MemoryStream` to accomplish this. So it is not directly accessing the I/O resources. When creating an instance of any stream adapter type (e.g. `StreamWriter`) you must pass a backing store stream to the constructor (e.g. `new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream())`), that the adapter stream then uses to read/write from/to the specific resource. The access of `StreamWriter` to e.g. a file or memory is therefore indirect. Read/ write operations are delegated to the underlying backing store stream.
The naming convention also expresses this relationship. It's a Stream*Reader* not a ReadableStream. It reads *from* a stream. It's a XML*Writer* and not a XmlStream (or FileStream).

### Q2

An adapter connects two incompatible interfaces or modules. In your graphics you can clearly see that the task of a stream adapter is to connect e.g. simple text, XML to the byte representation based stream object. The adapter **hides** the underlying stream details to the consumer. This allows you e.g. to use a `StreamWriter` to write a plain `string` to a `Stream` in a more convenient way, without caring about the real byte representation (a stream itself only knows bytes). The adapter knows how to transform the incompatible data in order to make it compatible.  That's the nature of an adapter. Because it connects stream incompatible data input/output to/from an actual stream, it is called "Stream Adapter". It adapts to a stream.

A decorator extends the behavior of the decorated object. It implements the base type of the decorated object and wraps an actual implementation in order to extend its behavior. This allows to add features to an existing object without violating the Open Closed Principle. So when the wrapped (decorated) object is extended (modified) then the wrapping (decorating) object is safe from modification.

The stream adapter *uses a* stream by converting and delegating data to it. A decorator stream *is a* stream and extends the behavior.

Both *Stream Adapters* and *Stream Decorators* are implementations of the design patterns: [Adapter Pattern](https://code-maze.com/adapter/) and [Decorator Pattern](https://code-maze.com/decorator-design-pattern/)

Comment: so StreamWriter  is not a stream?

Comment: No. It's an adapter that knows how to transform a `string` to a byte array, so that the data can be written to an underlying stream. It's a special connector.

Comment: I'm going to pick up a design pattern book to study now, is Adaptive Code via C# a good book or can you recommend one?

Comment: It's a simple wrapper. The decorator is a wrapper too but implements the wrapped base class to mimic the wrapped class.

Comment: Yes why not. You can try [Design Patterns in C#](http://file.allitebooks.com/20180622/Design%20Patterns%20in%20C.pdf) or [GoF Design Patterns](https://edeleastar.github.io/design-patterns/topic00/pdf/c-logica-gof-catalogue.pdf). The internet is full of eBooks and articles. You don't need to buy one. But it is always good to have one in the shelf.